# Which method for training neural networks works best?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, stochastic-gradient-descent

There are a dozens of different algorithms for training NNs. Most of them are stochastic gradient descent with some variations. Is there a comparative study that demonstrates some of them to be superior? Generally speaking, how do I decided which of those to pick for any given problem?

Comment: Surprisingly, vanilla SGD + momentum usually outperforms most of the recent variations, in terms of converging to the lowest validation loss.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent article explaining and comparing the different gradient descent algorithms can be found [here](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/).

Note that there are a lot of dominant optimization algorithms, because there **isn't** an algorithm that is superior than the rest.

That being said, from what I've seen the most common algorithm is [Adam](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980) and that is what I too use most of the times. The second most used, I think are [RMSProp](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~tijmen/csc321/slides/lecture_slides_lec6.pdf) and [Adadelta](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5701).